# How to restore administrative templates under the user configuration group policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I removed administrative templates under the user configurations group policies while I'm working on. How can I restore it?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the souliton. Open the Command Prompt as Administrator and write below line by line;

```
RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"
RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"
gpupdate /force
```